# Why does this "position.transform += Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)" change the value of position.transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity3d and c# scripts.

This is in the update function of a script attached to a mesh. If I comment out this line the position.transform stops changing, but if not it changes by a tiny amount every frame.

Comment: What is a "tiny amount"?

Comment: you say `position.transform`; is it possible you mean `transform.position`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `transform.position`, this is the global world space position, as opposed to `transform.localPosition`.  If your game object is part of a hierarchy, setting the global position has to compute a local position (translation) that results in the desired global position.  This requires a series of matrix multiplications, which can accumulate floating point error.  This is likely the source of the dither you're seeing.

Comment: It looks like that was the problem, thanks!